# Issues with running my first capybara appium test

Tags: rubygems, capybara, appium-ios

I am trying to run a simple capybara appium test on an iPad Air and I am getting a whole bunch of error. I am unsure about what exactly I am doing wrong.

```
require 'appium_capybara'
desired_caps_ios = {
    platform:       "Mac",
    platformName:  "iOS",
    platformVersion: "11.4",
    deviceName:    "iPhone Simulator",
    app:           "Safari",
}

url = "http://localhost:4723"

Capybara.register_driver(:appium) do |app|
    appium_lib_options = {
        server_url:           url
    }
    all_options = {
        appium_lib:  appium_lib_options,
        caps:        desired_caps_ios,
    }
    Appium::Capybara::Driver.new app, all_options
end

Capybara.default_driver = :appium
```

I am getting the following error:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/appium_lib_core-1.7.0/lib/appium_lib_core/common/base/bridge/w3c.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::PointerActions::DEFAULT_MOVE_DURATION
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.12.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/interactions/pointer_actions.rb:21: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT_MOVE_DURATION was here

I have tried to navigate over to the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.12.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/interactions/pointer_actions.rb and tried to comment out the DEFAULT_MOVE_DURATION line of code in the gem file, even tried to change permissions but it won't let me. I have no more about how to fix this.

Comment: That's a warning not an error, is it actually stoping your code from working?

Comment: I've tried to go into the pointer_actions.rb file and it won't let me comment out the line referring to DEFAULT_MOVE_DURATION, i've even tried changed the permission but that won't work either

Comment: No clue why that would be, but it's a warning not an error -  so it shouldn't be stopping anything from working anyway.  Do you have an actual error that you're getting?

Comment: This is the only thing that I am getting but nothing really starts up, I'm completely new to capybara, I've been using appium to write out mobile tests for an ios app, the simulator pops up but nothing is happening here, is that normal?

Comment: I don't know if it's normal because I don't know what you're actually doing - as it is the question you've posted isn't really valid because all you've posted is a warning which wouldn't actually cause a problem.

Comment: I'm just trying to run a sample test and see if it works then I will start testing what I need to test, I hope that makes sense.